# Linux Mint 20 - Switch users doesn't work correctly

Tags: linux-mint, gnu-screen, cinnamon, freeze

When the Account Switch is made, Linux Mint collapses, as shown in the figure below.

[image]

Often it is necessary to restart the computer in a forced way. I used Ubuntu and had no such problem.